# Small Business Server 2011 and Remote access to documents

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

Assume I'm working away from the office; its a hotel computer Windows 7, Office 2010 and fast - so the best possible conditions.

Using Companyweb - Every time I open a document, I have to go through the logon process - seems odd to have to do that. Is this a 'by design' feature or is something wrong with my configuration?

When I do open the documents, are they being stored somewhere locally and should I be looking to delete on this computer - or are they in a temporary file?

Comment: Are you login into Citrix?  Or is it more of a SonicWall NetExtender type deal?

Comment: Neither. Small Business Server Remote Web Access (its a feature of SBS).

Answer (score 0):

Something simple to check would be to make sure your Forms Based Authentication service is enabled.  You wouldn't happen to have a 2003 or 2007 SBS box up and running?  Reason I ask is I've seen this issue when migrating exchange from 2003 to 2010 and it isn't passing authentication properly.